# method undefined for type Java, nested classes

Tags: java, arrays, nested-class

I'm running into some trouble with nested classes on a project for school. 
Currently, I'm trying to write a method to insert an item into a ragged array data structure.
It uses an object created by a nested class to keep track of the 2d array location in order to get the indexes to insert at. However, I am getting the error "The method findEnd(E) is undefined for the type RaggedArrayList.ListLoc" on the line:

```
insertLoc.findEnd(item)
```

I have searched extensively both on stackoverflow as well as around the web and have not found the answer yet. If I have missed it and this is redundant (there are a lot of "method undefined for type questions", I know) then I apologize.

Here is the relevant code >>

nested class for ListLoc object:

```
private class ListLoc {
  public int level1Index;
  public int level2Index;

  public ListLoc() {}

  public ListLoc(int level1Index, int level2Index) {
     this.level1Index = level1Index;
     this.level2Index = level2Index;            
  }

  public int getLevel1Index() {
     return level1Index;
  }

  public int getLevel2Index() {
     return level2Index;
  }

  // since only used internally, can trust it is comparing 2 ListLoc's
  public boolean equals(Object otherObj) {
     return (this == otherObj);
  }
}
```

Method to find the last index of a matching item (not part of ListLoc nested class):

```
private ListLoc findEnd(E item){
  E itemAtIndex;

  for (int i = topArray.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
     L2Array nextArray = (L2Array)topArray[i];

     if (nextArray == null) {
        continue;

     } else {

        for (int j = nextArray.items.length -1; j >= 0; j--) {
           itemAtIndex = nextArray.items[j];
           if (itemAtIndex.equals(item)) {
              return new ListLoc(i, j+1);
           }
        }
     }
  }

  return null;
```

}

Method attempting to add a new value to the ragged array:

```
boolean add(E item){
  ListLoc insertLoc = new ListLoc();
  insertLoc.findEnd(item);

  int index1 = insertLoc.getLevel1Index();
  int index2 = insertLoc.getLevel2Index();

  L2Array insertArray = (L2Array)topArray[index1];
  insertArray.items[index2] = item;

  return true;
```

}

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Don't bother adding the homework tag anymore. :)  We're not using it.  I've already removed it for you.

Comment: Well at quick glance I would say it is because your method is private, or that the scope is wrong (the method is not in the correct location). You say that the method is not in `ListLoc`, but you are calling it like it is.

Comment: Didn't realize the homework tag wasn't used anymore. Sorry. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to bet that changing this:

```
ListLoc insertLoc = new ListLoc();
insertLoc.findEnd(item);
```

To this:

```
ListLoc insertLoc = findEnd(item);
```

Will fix your problem.

You're trying to call `findEnd` on the `ListLoc` class, but if you actually look at `ListLoc`, it's not defined there. When you tried to call `findEnd` on the `insertLoc` object, it fails because `insertLoc` is an instance of `ListLoc`, which we already said doesn't contain `findEnd`.

That being said, I'm going to bet that `findItem` is actually declared in the same class as the `add` method (let's just call it `MyList`), so you wanted to actually call `MyList.findEnd`, not the non-existent `ListLoc.findEnd`.

Comment: Yup. That did it. Obviously, I'm still learning. Scope continues to be a challenge for me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: One way to think of it for this scenario is that the `.` accessor on objects help to define the scope. When you said `insertLoc.findEnd`, the `.` says, "look for non-static methods and fields in the class of `insertLoc` (the `ListLoc` class) and invoke or access them for the `insertLoc` object." For accessing methods and fields in the _same_ class, remember that our call to `findEnd` is exactly the same as if we called `this.findEnd` (try it!), so it's also defining the scope. But here, the variable is `this`, and it ultimately gives us the class that defines `add`. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered your own question.. You're trying to call findEnd on a ListLoc object, but ListLoc doesn't define a findEnd method. You need to either

a) Add an implementation for findLoc to ListLoc or

b) Call findLoc on the proper object (you haven't provided information about the other class so I can't say too much about it)

Answer (score 0):

> Method to find the last index of a matching item (not part of ListLoc nested class):

Right - it's *not* part of `ListLoc`... but when you call it here:

```
ListLoc insertLoc = new ListLoc();
insertLoc.findEnd(item);
```

... you're trying to call it as if it *is* part of the class. It isn't, so you can't call it like that.

Either move it into `ListLoc`, or change the way you're calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am reading this correct, but from your explanation is looks like the findEnd method is defined outside of your class, therefore ListLoc indeed doesn't have a method by that name...

Where is your private ListLoc findEnd(E item) defined?